# Sending mail through cron not working

Tags: python, linux, email, cron, smtp

I have a script written in python which works properly. When executing the script on shell, the script properly sends the mail. But now, I am using a cron job so that it executes the script every minute. The script is being executed but no mail is being sent. I had a look in /var/log/syslog and found the following error message:

```
Dec 29 20:39:01 noor-Inspiron-5520 CRON[25045]: (noor) CMD (/home/mail/call )
Dec 29 20:39:01 noor-Inspiron-5520 sSMTP[25048]: Unable to locate mail
Dec 29 20:39:01 noor-Inspiron-5520 sSMTP[25048]: Cannot open mail:25
Dec 29 20:39:01 noor-Inspiron-5520 CRON[25044]: (noor) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x0001, #012)
```

Any idea why this error is happening and how to correct it ?

Comment: Might be a different `PATH` for cron.

Comment: Cron is a stickler for details. Checkout http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: @Harald, what do you mean by different PATH ?

Comment: The PATH environment variable. You should reall post your cron line.